# Finding object with lowest value for some key, in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, min

In my Javascript program, I have a list of `Person` objects.

For example

```
[
     "Michael": {
          "age": 45,
          "position": "manager",
          ...
     },
    "Dwight": {
          "age": 36,
          "position": "assistant manager",
          ...
     },
    ....
]
```

I want to find the youngest `Person`.

I've accomplished this by creating two arrays: one of all the `Person`s and one of all their ages, and getting the index of the lowest age and applying it to the first array. Like:

```
var arrayOfPersons = [persons[0], persons[1], ....];
var arrayOfAges = [persons[0].age, persons[1].age, ....];
var min = arrayOfAges.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, arrayOfAges));
var youngestPerson = arrayOfPerson[min];
```

The problem with this is it is inefficient doesn't seem like the best way. Also it doesn't deal with the fact that there may be a tie for youngest.

Does anyone know of a more native, simpler way to do this?

Comment: Your list seems wrong. Is it meant to be an array of objects or single object with person names as a keys?

Comment: arrayOfAges should be array of values not objects

Comment: @Heikki It's meant to be a list of `Person` objects

Comment: @theinvisible It is. It's a list of age values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the persons array by age property and pick first one:

```
var persons = [
    { name: 'Michael', age: 45, position: 'manager' },
    { name: 'Dwight', age: 36, position: 'assistant manager' },
    { name: 'Foo', age: 99, position: 'foo' },
    { name: 'Bar', age: 37, position: 'bar' }
];

persons.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.age > b.age;
});

console.log('Youngest person: ', persons[0]);
```